# File array showing "." and ".." in Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dropdown

Im working on a Dropdown menu which lists all files in a specific folder.
In general it works pretty well. However the Dropdown menu shows all PDF files in the folder declared (which is great!) but also shows "." , "..", and "@eaDir" in the dropdown menu (which isnt that great!)

Ive tried to add something like this

```
 $ignoredFiles = array('.', '..', '@eaDir');
```

But it dont quite know where to call this to execlude all the extentions

This is my PHP Code

```
  <select name="euvertragsklausel" id="euvertragsklausel" class="pdfliste">
<option value="">- Verfahrensverzeichnis -
<?php 
$dirPath = dir('euvertragsklausel');
 $ignoredFiles = array('.', '..','@eaDir');
$FileArray = array();
while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
    {
   $FileArray[ ] = trim($file);
    }
$dirPath->close();
sort($FileArray);
$c = count($FileArray);
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{

    echo "<option value=\"" . $FileArray[$i] . "\">" . $FileArray[$i] . "</option>\n";
}

?>
</select>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" value="PDF  Öffnen!"
         onclick="gotoeuklausel()">
         <br /><br />
```

And my Javascript. However i dont think the problem is in here

```
function gotoeuklausel(){
      if(document.getElementById('euvertragsklausel').value) {
    window.location.href =             "content/dokumente/euvertragsklausel/"+document.getElementById('euvertragsklausel').value;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of the result as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use in_array function

```
while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
    {
     if (! in_array($file, $ignoredFiles)) {
        $FileArray[ ] = trim($file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats what ive been missing *facepalm*
Thanks!